# Java: Map of maps with identical keys

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, nested, hashtable

Consider a huge CSV with the following structure (modified for simplicity):

```
ID, NAME,  ADDRESS, PHONE, MAIL
1,  Jon,   UK,      403,  jon@skeet.com
2,  Marc,  UK,      292,  marc@gravel.com
3,  Darin, France,  291,  darin@dimitrov.com
...
(Some million records)
```

The natural data structure for quick fetch is a Hash Table, where every `ID` is a key and `NAME,  ADDRESS, PHONE, MAIL` are the value. My dillema is the data structure of the values.

Storing it in a `HashMap` where every row header is the key is a waste of space, because the  row headers are exactly the same for each row. Storing it as an Array would lose the metadata for each item, because the reader

I was thinking of two approaches:

- Overload Java's Hashmap. The row headers will be stored once, and every `ID` will be associated with a String Array. The `get()` method will be overloaded so that it will return a  map between the header rows and the corresponding fields in the row.
- Create a dumb class which stores the data for each row using getters and setters (`row.getMail()`, `row.getAddress()`,...)

What's the right way to go, in terms of memory efficiency, type safety and speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the "dumb" class instead of overloading a collection.

I don't know about type safety or speed, but I would say your code will be more readable.  Those values go together; encapsulate them in an object to emphasize the point.  Is there any behavior associated with them besides get/set?  If yes, then so much the better.

Answer (score 2):

While the 'dumb' class is the cleaner approach it's obviously less generic than the map of maps approach and would require parsing logic specific to the CSV format - so there's a trade-off.

What is probably less of a trade-off are your concerns about memory efficiency - strings are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) so each of the row maps will actually have the same string instance in them, so the overhead will only be down to the reference to each string.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about the wasted space unless you know you have a problem. i.e. you have many GB of data.

If you want to know a way to make it more efficient you can use a combination of `Map<String, Integer>` to lookup the keys, and use an `Object[]` for each row.  To lookup by name, you find the number to look up first.

An even more efficient approach is to store the data by column instead of by row.  This is more efficient as you tend to have much more rows than columns

```
Map<String, List> columns = ...
```

You can lookup a cell by name first and then by entry in the list.  If you want to use primitive types you can use `int[]` or `double[]` or `TIntArrayList` and `TDoubleArrayList` to save memory.  The `ADDRESS` country could be an enumerated type.

Unless you have millions of rows, I would just keep it simple.

Comment: I do have some millions of records.

Comment: In that case, it could be worth testing whether it makes enough difference to matter (less than that I wouldn't bother)  You may still find that while it saves say 100 MB, it will only mean your servers free memory increases by 100 MB but keeping the code simpler is actually a better idea.